# Could EF cause excessive memory usage in C#?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, memory-management

I have a multi threading console application that written in C# and Entity Framework 4.0.
Yesterday, when I monitored the program for couple hours, it uses about 100MB, but this morning it becomes 500MB. Just wondering if EF will eventually become big because of caching?
Or should I somehow refresh it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you checking the memory usage, if you are using Task Manager then it does not reflect the correct memory usage. Its better if you use [some memory profiler for .Net](http://memprofiler.com/), also see [What Are Some Good .NET Profilers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927/what-are-some-good-net-profilers). You can also try [dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) to see which object is taking memory.

try disabling  `ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled` under your data context and see if it helps, but I still think using a memory profiler would give you a clear picture of what is going on with your applicaiton.

Comment: My LazyLoadingEnabled  is set to true. May be I try to look into it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a valid reason to monitor memory usage, there's *typically* none. Garbage collector will kick in when there's a need for memory and will empty unused one.

As long as you are not keeping references to non-used objects somewhere, memory usage should not be a concern in garbage collected environments.

Comment: That said, there are *lots* of ways you could keep unused references and prevent them from being collected. A memory profiler might help (like [this](http://memprofiler.com/) or [this](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/))

Comment: I am afraid objects that cached in the EF will not be collected by Garbage Collector.

Comment: They will, as soon as you dispose your context and have no more entity references. Unless you are keeping (maybe not-so-obvious) references to the entities or the context somewhere, they should be disposed and collected automatically. That's why I recommended using a memory profiler.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, EF will cache the entities you queried ,maybe this is a reason ,you can turn it off in dbcontext.config and c any effected.